# How to format json data with rails helper before passing it to handlebar template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, json, view-helpers, handlebars.js

I can't figure out how to format json data through a rails helper before passing the value to a handlebar template.

Like how do I use existing helper methods on the values?

I know you can register a helper with the Handlebars.registerHelper method, but can I use my rails helper methods on the json data before passing it to handlebar?

Comment: Using [Poirot][1] does the exact job... with [Handlebars.js][2] or [Mustache][3]. It allows using template partails that both rails and javascript can use... it also allows the use of all the rails helpers and allows you to provide an optional view class if needed!


  [1]: https://github.com/olivernn/poirot
  [2]: http://handlebarsjs.com/
  [3]: https://github.com/janl/mustache.js

Comment: UPDATE: Poirot doesnt actually allow you to use the view class methods in your js template as they are obviously rendered clientside and don't have access to them... its still good for sharing templates between client and server.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a template for this (e.g. `method.json.erb`) and render your objects yourself.
Just remove the `render :json => @object` in your controller then.

Your template should then look something like

```
{
    'field1': '<%= @object.field1.to_json %>',
    'field2': '<%= @object.field2.to_json %>'
}
```

**EDIT**: I'm not sure if this renders your default layout also. You might switch to use a partial instead:

`format.json { render :partial => "methos.json.erb" }`

Comment: I'm using handlebar for server and client side templating so this wouldnt be ideal.